# Regex to check if string contains Alphanumeric Characters and Spaces only - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I have so far:

```
function checkTitle(){
    reg = /^[\w ]+$/;
    a = reg.test($("#title").val());    
    console.log(a);
}
```

So far in my tests it catches all special characters except `_`.
How do I catch all special characters including `_` in the current function?

I need the string to only have Alphanumeric Characters and Spaces. Appreciate the help cause I am having a hard time understanding **regex** patterns.

Thanks!

Comment: Oops I deleted the comment right before your response, I thought the answers were sufficient!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that `\w` matches all alphanumeric values **and** underscore.

Rather than parsing the entire string, I'd just look for any unwanted characters. For example

```
var reg = /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/;
```

If the result of `reg.test` is `true`, then the string fails validation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks. Been working with stronger regex libraries lately. Haven't had to deal with unicode in JS yet.

Comment: @Phil: If you ever have to, take a look at [XRegExp with Unicode plugins](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).

Comment: @Phil what if I  want to allow parentheses with this, Please Suggest

Comment: @AjaySuwalka wouldn't you just include parentheses in the character class then? `[^A-Za-z0-9 ()]`

Comment: @Phil Thanks, I added it, I was just a little skeptical about adding that whether it would work or not. :

Answer (score 3):

Since you are stating you are new to RegExp, I might as well include some tips with the answer. I suggest the following regexp:

```
/^[a-z\d ]+$/i
```

Here:

1. There is no need for the upper case A-Z because of the `i` flag in the end, which matches in a case-insensitive manner
2. \d special character represents digits