# Regular expression for alphanumeric in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want a regex for alphanumeric characters in angularJS, I've tried some regex like "(\d[a-z])" but they allow me to enter only number as well as only alphabets. But I want a regex which won't allow me to enter them.

Example:
**121232, abchfe, abd()*, 42232^5$** are some example of **invalid** input.
**12fUgdf, dGgs1s23** are some **valid** inputs.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric

Comment: Similar questions asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692187/regex-to-check-if-string-contains-alphanumeric-characters-and-spaces-only-java

Comment: You want a regex that allows only digits and letters, and requires at least one of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one requires atleast one of each (a-z, A-Z and 0-9):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. this expression satisfied at least one number and one character and no other special characters

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

in angular can test like:

```
$scope.str = '12fUgdf';
var pattern = new RegExp('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$');
$scope.testResult = pattern.test($scope.str);
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GNOD9w3uNTZVExzqIjvx?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return a replaced result, then this would work:

```
var a = 'Test123*** TEST';
var b = a.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
console.log(b);
```

This would return:

```
Test123TEST
```

OR

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/
```

the above regex allows spaces in side a string and restrict special characters.It Only allows a-z, A-Z, 0-9, Space, Underscore and dash.

Comment: You should go for regex.test(str) as he never asked for a replace

Answer (score 0):

try this one : `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

```
dGgs1s23-valid
12fUgdf-valid,
121232-invalid, 
abchfe-in valid,
 abd()*- invalid, 
42232^5$- invalid
```